# Compiling Orange Pi on macOS

Tags: osx, compiling

Following this guide:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Orange_Pi

I encounter this problem:

```
input in flex scanner failed
make[1]: *** [orangepi_zero_defconfig] Error 2
make: *** [orangepi_zero_defconfig] Error 2
```

After I enter this command:

```
make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- orangepi_zero_defconfig
```

I have attempted using a capital and lower-case z as the first letter in zero as well as removing the space between `eabi-` and `orangepi`

Comment: Post the **complete** output, not just a few lines. Do it without `-j4` to make the output clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the guide,

```
$ git clone --depth 1 git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
$ cd u-boot
$ make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- orangepi_one_defconfig
```

Even I use arm-eabi- instead of arm-none-eabi-, it works as guide says under **Ubuntu 14.04**. 
(doesn't matter indeed)
No change to the config file.

Would you check if flex is installed on your host?

My host has 'flex 2.5.35'.

** You'd better follow the guide as it is, even lower-cases and spaces ^^